# How do I expose a websocket in Openshift V3?

Tags: openshift

I am trying to deploy a slightly modified version of the Java 7 EE example Webservice Chat code. I wanted to get everything bootstrapped and talking before starting to code.

The endpoint code is as follows:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat") 
public class Websocket { 

@OnOpen 
public void open(Session session) { 
} 

@OnClose 
public void close(Session session) { 
} 

@OnError 
public void onError(Throwable error) {
} 

@OnMessage 
public void message(String message, Session client) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    System.out.println("message: " + message);
    for (Session peer : client.getOpenSessions()) { 
        peer.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Then, I have a client that connects to it with JavaScript. That connects with this code:

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.hostname + ":8000" + document.location.pathname + "chat";

var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

I believe OpenShift v3 is using 8080 in the route to explose the webapp, but I can't seem to connect to this websocket on any port with any websocket test tools.

The application is currently deployed here:  http://wildfly10-coredump.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/

I am new to Openshift v3, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OpenShift V3 supports running WebSockets over the same port. When the service is exposed via a route, that will be port 80 externally for HTTP traffic including WebSockets. Only difference will be sub path in URL used.

Comment: Yep! There it is ... never occurred to me that it would be exposed by default like that! Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it correct!

Comment: I'm kind of new to openshift, can you provide an example?